# search/sort 0 to many relations table in gridview yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have tender table which has none to many acc managers. i used kartik select2 widget to save those via TenderAccManager model.

Here, tender_acc_maanger table stores tender and acc_manager tables id.

Now i want to show the acc managers name (accManager is the relation name in TenderAccManager model)in comma separated way in gridview, 
so far i came up with this (inside gridview widget):

```
[
    'label' => 'A/C Manager Name',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function($data) {
        $accManagers = TenderAccManager::find()
            ->where(['tender_id' => $data->id])
            ->all();

        $value = '';
        $i = 0;
        foreach($accManagers as $accManager) {
            if($i > 0) {
                $value .= ', ';
            }
            $value .= $accManager->accManager->name;
            $i++;
        }

        return $value;
    }
],
```

the code is working, but i want the searching and sorting function too like other fields in gridview, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/**
 * This is the model class for table "tender".

class Tender extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

```
public $manager;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'tender';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name', 'cost'], 'required'],
        [['cost'], 'number'],
        [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'cost' => 'Cost',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getTenderManagers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TenderManager::className(), ['tender_id' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getTenderManagerList()
{
    $list  = '';
    foreach ($this->tenderMaangers as $managers) {
        $list .=$managers->manager->name.' ';
    }
    return $list;
}
```

}

/**
 * TenderSearch represents the model behind the search form about `frontend\models\Tender`.
 */

class TenderSearch extends Tender {

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['id'], 'integer'],
        [['name', 'manager'], 'safe'],
        [['cost'], 'number'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function scenarios() {
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params) {
    $query = Tender::find();
    $query->joinWith(['tenderManagers.manager']);
    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['manager'] = [
        'asc' => ['manager.name' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['manager.name' => SORT_DESC],
    ];

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'cost' => $this->cost,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tender.name', $this->name]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'manager.name', $this->manager]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

}

/**
 * This is the model class for table "tender_manager". */

class TenderManager extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'tender_maanger';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['tender_id', 'manager_id'], 'required'],
        [['tender_id', 'manager_id'], 'integer'],
        [['manager_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Manager::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['manager_id' => 'id']],
        [['tender_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Tender::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['tender_id' => 'id']],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'tender_id' => 'Tender ID',
        'manager_id' => 'Manager ID',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getManager()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Manager::className(), ['id' => 'manager_id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getTender()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Tender::className(), ['id' => 'tender_id']);
}
```

}

/**
 * This is the model class for table "manager".  */

class Manager extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'manager';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name'], 'required'],
        [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'name' => 'Name',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getTenderMaangers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TenderMaanger::className(), ['manager_id' => 'id']);
}
```

/*This is the grid code of index file for tender.  */

```
        [
            'attribute' => 'manager',
            'value' => function($model) {
               return $model->getTenderManagerList();
            },
        ],
```

Comment: your code helped me to understand things clearly and implement it successfully.

Comment: i'm having a little problem with joining,

as tender has many acc_managers, seems count returns the multiplied result, for ex, if i have one entry for tender but 3 acc man entry, the query returns 3 instead of one, how could i apply distinct here?

Comment: you cant use distinct keyword instead you have to use Inner Join  to list only matching records

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think that you should reconsider getting this info on the beginning of action, with eager load (this is lazy loading). Currently, you are going to perform database query on every row, and this is expensive operation (not needed to be).

I did not think a lot about it. My first idea about it is next one:

1) I guess that you in your Grid View list all tenders, and got one column where you want to list all Acc managers. When loading them (in Tender Search models search method, I guess) you should perform two joins (to relational many-to-many table and to Acc manager table). So, when this step is done you have all loaded eagerly and don't have to perform query to database in every row result in grid view. (Also, you should avoid performing queries in view anyway).

2) Well, you could in your Tender model have public member AccManagers, which is going to be "safe". When have this, in search, when configuring data provider, you can actually configure sort for this attribute. Sure, you should create that result from query on this attribute be comma separated list, or however you want it to look.

When done with loading data eagerly and sorting, you are ready for:

3) Filter data. Just, set andWhere part on search criteria in search model which will actually compare result string of your concatenation, or compare every AccManagers name with inserted value (it just depends how do you want filter to work).

These are just guidelines, I hope this will help you.

Best regards

Comment: i knew i wasn't doing things right as i did so far, but i couldn't figure out the better way, now your guideline about eager loading and not to query in view helped me to understand the concept, while amit kundaria's answer helped me to implement it. so both of your's answer is valuable to me.

Comment: Great. Yeah, I prefer to answer questions conceptually, because I think that implementation is something what can be learned/figured out relatively easy when developer exactly knows what does he want to achieve.